# Why am i getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyperclip

I'm new to python, so apologies in advance if I’m being stupid.

I'm having trouble importing the pyperclip module to my script. The following error pops up when i type in `import pyperclip`.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Pruthvi/Practice.py', wdir='C:/Users/Pruthvi')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Pruthvi\Practice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Having followed the steps in automate the boring stuff with python, I’ve successfully installed the module using `pip install pyperclip` and it was saved to the **c:\users\pruthvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages** directory by default.

Is this the right folder to save third-party modules and to import them after? Or is there some other reason why I can't import it?

Many thanks,
Pruthvi

Comment: run python --version

Comment: This is the output from my command prompt:  
unknown option --version--
unknown option --version--
expected long option
unknown option --version--
unknown option --version--
expected long option
unknown option --version--
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.

Comment: What python version do you have?

Comment: I have python 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was that my IDE (Spyder) was searching in the wrong folder for downloaded modules. All modules downloaded using pip get downloaded to the c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages directory by default. So I simply set my PATH (where the interpreter searches for files) to this directory.

Corey Schafer has a great video on how to set a PATH:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdIHeg4jj2c

Answer (score 0):

On LINUX, I tried to use:

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

and then it works for me.

I didn't have a technical answer for that, but it is related to python3 compatibility of the module